# How do I connect windows server vm from wan side of pfsense vm to lan side of pfsense

Tags: networking, router, virtualbox, pfsense

I am trying to get Windows Sever VM to connect to another Windows server VM on the LAN side of pfsense. Pfsense acts as a virtual router and I want to connect these two vms together and run as two domain controllers. but I cant get them to ping to each other. Do i have to create a firewall rule to let inbound traffic or is it not possible. I tried connecting the server vms with two nics and have each subnet on a different nic but I heard that was a bad idea and stopped it. Basically I want pfsense to act as another subnet. But I want it to be its own network. I have the pfsense bridged to my router and my main router acts as the wan.

Answer (score 0):

pfsense is not just a router. It is a firewall too.
If you do not need the firewall functionality you can disable it or you can configure the firewall to let you go through.

If I understand correctly you have this topology:

[vm-to-vm-through-pfsense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FSKT.jpg)

System / Andvanced / Firewall & NAT

Advanced Options

Disable Firewall => [X]Disable all packet filtering

(Read the note: Note: This converts pfSense into a routing only platform!)

If you do not want to disable the firewall functionality than add an any-to-any rule on the WAN interface firewall.

[any-to-any-on-wan-fw-pfsense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osj4F.jpg)

Hint: If ping does not work check the firewall settings of your Windows hosts.